# Drag and drop from finder into illustrator without it creating a new document

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I'm dropping svg files (about 15 icons) from finder, into my open doc in illustrator, but instead of placing them onto that artboard, illustrator opens up a new document for each one.

How can I get it to just paste into the file I want them in?

Comment: Just place them—why do you need to drag and drop them specifically?

Comment: It's inconsistent. And, it's faster.

- clicking and dragging from finder onto the artboard works just fine for jpg and png files, as well as ai, pdf, and eps files, but for svg files, a new document for each one is created automatically. 

- placing solves the problem (thanks for that btw), but it's slower. The way I have the items organized in directories, it's faster to navigate and click and drag within finder than within illustrator's place popup, that brings me back to the last directory accessed.

Comment: on windows it depends on where on illustrators window you drop them. If you drop them on the canvas they become placed if you do not then it opens them

Comment: I think Billy's answer should work for you, but I still wonder if you know about [Default Folder X](http://stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/)? The best feature, I'd say is that it has a hotkey that you can press in the open/save dialogs `Shift+Alt+↑`, and will navigate to the active folder in Finder. So basically if you have the project file open and active, you can just tell the dialog to navigate there in an instant, instead of navigating to the path manually. There's also an option to default to the current document's folder in save dialogs.

Comment: @Joonas you can drag and drop a file or folder to any open/save/etc dialog and it'll auto navigate there already

Comment: @Cai While it's better than nothing. It's not as convenient as what the application does.

Comment: @Joonas fair enough, I haven't used the app so wouldn't know. Just thought it was worth pointing out that it's easy enough to get to somewhere already open in Finder already

Comment: @Cai I always thought I was kinda.. Weird. Most applications support some form of file dragging straight to the application, so dragging a file to the open dialog seems a bit unnecessary. As far as saving dialogs go, you can use a shortcut, which I'd say is simpler and there's that other feature I mentioned, that automatically navigates save dialogs to the folder path of the current document. I'd highly recommend you try it.

Comment: @Joonas No, I didn't know about it - thanks for the lead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found that if you click and drag an SVG file, then hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>,  as you drop it on the artboard, the object will be placed in the current document.  This works on Windows, Illustrator CC 2017, not sure about Mac or older versions of Illustrator.  Perhaps you could try it and see.

The behaviour for dragging and dropping SVGs seems to be different compared to other file formats.  Clicking and dragging an AI file into Illustrator, or raster image file doesn't require the Shift key trick.

Comment: Yep, works on Mac here, both CS6 and CC. Bizarre that only SVGs work like that...

Comment: @Cai Sometimes Illustrator is bizarre. This isn't intuitive at all, and Adobe should fix it, although they'd probably say it's a "feature", not a bug.

Comment: I would like to point out that no applictation of sufficient complexity is intuitive. First of all intuitive verues across people so something that may be intuitive to you is not intuitive for me and vice versa. Secondly design history kills quite a bit of intuition of software. Things become automatically more diffuse as you tack stuff on top of stuff and as your desin/implementation team grows and changes. Illustrator is about as old software as you are most likely going to run into.

Comment: @ BillyKerr think I don't have enough clout to mark my question as _solved_ with you answer, but it did do the trick. Thanks!  
@joojaa what are ya, an illustrator spokesperson? Tell your team to make this behavior consistent for all file formats!

Comment: @AlexShaikevich No but im just saying all applications are full of logical flaws like this. I have never used and application with no logic flaw that can be found within a few weeks of use. apps that are intuitive dont exist. The  only reasons people think they do is because either they havd grown accustomed with the weird decissions or because they never do anything remotely hard.

Comment: @joojaa No? Well don't let that stop you. Perhaps next you can share your observations on how typefaces differ, on a question asking about kerning.